# sql exception,no such column exist(android)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to fetch record according to item_name..but it gives sql exception no such column: Roti exist.
        query of my code is there

```
    db.query(TABLE_1, new String[] { KEY_ITEM_CALORIES }, KEY_ITEM_NAME + "=" + item_name, null, null, null, null, null);
```

whats is the problem in this query?

Comment: Uhm... your table does not contain the column named "Roti".

Comment: my column name is breakfast items and roti is item name

Answer (score 0):

you can make like that

```
Cursor mCursor=db.query(tablename, new String[] {"columnname1","columnname2"},"KEY_ITEM_NAME=?",new String[] { item_name }, null, null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery
```

`("select * from Table_Name where Column_Name ='"+ value +"'", null)`